# Turning a k-space integral into an energy integral for a conductivity tensor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, tensor-calculus

Looking over a derivation of the conductivity tensor for magneto-resistance, I got stuck trying to go from (1.133) to (1.134), transforming the k-space integral into one over energy.

[image: pg 29 D. Arovas Lecture Notes Condensed Matter Physics]

In this problem, $\epsilon (k) = \frac{1}{2}\hbar^2 m_{\alpha \beta}^{-1} k^\alpha k^\beta$ with a summation over x,y,z, while $\Gamma_{\nu \beta}$ is a tensor coming from the Boltzmann equation of motion.

I also don't follow how (1.135) comes about, as it suggests

$$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{n}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \epsilon g(\epsilon)(-\partial f^0/\partial \epsilon)d\epsilon}$$

which is in no way obvious.

These lecture notes are from Page 29 of https://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/winter2010/physics211b/LECTURES/211_COURSE.pdf

A point in the right direction would help a lot. Thanks!